# What is the difference between these compiler directives?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

What, if anything, is the difference between these directives?

```
#ifdef FOO

#if defined FOO

#if defined(FOO)
```

I'm using the CCS compiler, but I'm interested in other **C** compilers as well.

Comment: They are spelled differently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what I've seen, the main use for `#if defined` is to do a check for multiple macro definitions on one line.  Otherwise, for single macro definition conditionals, they are identical as far as I know.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
#if defined(FOO) && defined(BAR)
    printf("foobar!\n");
#else
    printf("nothing.\n");
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ tcc -DFOO -run a.c 
nothing.
$ tcc -DBAR -run a.c 
nothing.
$ tcc -DFOO -DBAR -run a.c 
foobar!
```

Also, the above program compiles fine with `gcc -Wall -ansi a.c` so that suggests `#if defined` is correct ANSI C.  Moreover, [this ANSI C summary from 1987](http://www.ericgiguere.com/articles/ansi-c-summary.html) lists `#if defined` as newly defined behavior for the preprocessor under ANSI standards -- this *should* be standard across any ANSI-compliant compiler you will use.

If you weren't using `#if defined`, you'd have to do

```
#ifdef FOO
#ifdef BAR
    printf("foobar!\n");
#endif /* BAR */
#endif /* FOO */
```

Also, [the Redhat manual for the C preprocessor](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-4-Manual/cpp/conditional-syntax.html) says

> `#if defined MACRO` is precisely equivalent to `#ifdef MACRO`.

Comment: Ah, I thought it might be something like that, and I was experimenting with it while you were answering. :-)

Comment: Also, I've found that #if !defined(FOO) is the same as #ifndef FOO

Answer (score 3):

All 3 forms are exactly equivalent and valid, according to the C99 standard.  Generally `#ifdef` is preferred because it is shorter than the other two forms, but there are situations where you would want to use the other forms:

- If testing for the definitions of multiple symbols, or more complex expressions:

  ```
  #if defined(ONE_THING) && define(ANOTHER_THING) && (3 < 4)
  ...
  #endif
  ```
- If you have multiple clauses, it's much easier to use `#elif defined(...)` than `#else`, `#ifdef`:

  ```
  #if defined(ONE_THING)
  ...
  #elif defined(ANOTHER_THING)
  ...
  #elif defined(THIRD_THING)
  ...
  #else
  ...
  #endif
  ```

The usage of parentheses with `defined` is optional; I prefer using them to add clarity.

Answer (score 1):

**#ifdef** is short for **#if defined** and I think you don't need parenthesis on neither, so basically they are the same.

Coming from Turbo C, I'm used to looking at **#ifdef** rather than **#if defined**

Answer (score 1):

Originally there was only `#ifdef`, but when `#if` came along it was necessay to have `defined()`  in order for `#if` to superset `#ifdef`.